# Debugging Jquery for wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having trouble getting Jquery to work in my theme.

I have the following three files: functions.php, jquery.min.js (located in js folder and has jquery 3.5.1 copied into it), scripts.js (in the js folder)

functions php code is this:

```
function include_jquery(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', '', 1, true);
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery');
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');
```

Code for the scripts.js file is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
alert('test');
})
```

thank you in advance

link to the site I am testing it on https://testthemedesign.littleseabear.com/

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to suggest that you need to enqueue 'jquery' on wp_head' not in 'wp_footer' so replace that last parameter of your code 'wp_enqueue_script' with "false".
Now the actual problem is that you have to register that new jquery.js file as jquery in wordpress, And then enqueue it.
Following is my changes in your code :

```
function include_jquery(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', '', 1, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery');
```

One more thing if you are using any child theme then replace that get_template_directory_uri with get_stylesheet_directory_uri

`wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', '', 1, false );`